# Understanding and breaking down pointing requirements

Tags: attitude-determination-and-control, flight-control

“< 1 deg, 3σ total angle pointing stability” - What does the 3sigma indicate? Does this mean that 99.7% of the total pointing error (which I assume is computed via a sim), is within 1 deg? If it was 1-sigma, would that mean only 68% of the pointing errors need to be within 1 deg? What does total angle mean vs single-axis? Does total angle mean you RSS the x,y,z pointing errors?

Comment: Can you edit your post to provide some context?

Answer (score 7):

In my professional experience in writing spaceflight software requirements, reading them, implementing them, validating them, and verifying them, these "what does that mean" questions come up way more often than anyone ever expects. It turns out that requirements from you-in-the-past are just as mysterious as requirements from other people.

That said:

- yes, your understanding of sigma as being used for the standard deviation percentages is correct in both [manufacturing](https://ca.indeed.com/career-advice/career-development/3-sigma) and for other errors like pointing errors (though I really should get an authoritative source.  I like that source's phrasing though

  > This means that 99.7% of all outcomes are within this range of accuracy

  So if we do, for example, a Monte Carlo simulation, only 0.3% of our cases should exhibit pointing errors beyond the stated limit.

  THAT SAID, if someone said to me "no no, over the cumulative time of this set of simulation runs, we're only pointing outside the limits 0.3% of that time even though all of our cases do violate that limit" ... I would be *wary*, because the simulation parameters themselves are going to be defined per-case with their own means and sigmas, generally (aside from some variables not assumed to be normally distributed). I don't know if that's a fight I can win on a contract level to say that the requirements weren't met.  Hence, it might be a good idea to codify exactly what you mean in the requirement (99.7% of simulation cases do not exceed this pointing error, to be verified by Monte Carlo simulation) instead of relying on the commonly-understood meaning of the words.

  Have I been bitten by someone doing this kind of thing before?  I can't say, but I have a headache.
- I would expect total angle to mean you're comparing two vectors (e.g. the boresight vector of an antenna and the vector from the a particular part of that antenna to its nominal target) and taking the subtended angle between them, e.g. by solving the dot product $\vec{a} \cdot \vec{b} = ab\cos{\theta}$, or but I have explicitly seen it defined as the RSS of three Euler angles. (I agree with David Hammen's comment that this isn't the right thing to do, and there are extra ways to find a single total angle between two arbitrary orientations because of [Euler's Rotation Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_rotation_theorem) including by representing them as quaternions).  Single axis would mean one axis. Again, explicitly defining it in your requirements can save you a headache later.

  Note that if you're using Euler angles to specify rotations you should also specify exactly what they mean:  these are rotation applied in this order around these axes of this defined coordinate system to end up at this transformed coordinate system.  I have seen people try to define them much more casually.

I've just realized that I've been writing this assuming that you are writing requirements instead of interpreting them. If your job is to **interpret** ambiguous requirements:  start asking questions, maybe even push for a revision in the requirements themselves if you can.  If you get pushback along the lines of "you should know what this means" a) that's a bad engineering culture and b) try to get agreement right there about what it means and write that down, including who and when is defining it.

Comment: Love this " It turns out that requirements from you-in-the-past are just as mysterious as requirements from other people."

Comment: Minor nitpick: I would never use the RSS of three Euler angles. Calculating the single axis rotation angle error using quaternions is trivial. Given two unit quaternions $Q_1$ and $Q_2$, the angular difference between them is the arcsine of the magnitude of the vector part of $Q_1 \times Q_2^*$ (or $Q_1^* \times Q_2$, or any similar combination).

Comment: @DavidHammen neither would I, but I've seen it in practice at NASA at least once :(

Comment: In my experience outside of spaceflight a 3σ spec *is applied to a Gaussian fit* to the distribution of measured deviations, whether or not that distribution is really Gaussian. It does not necessarily mean that what's outside the spec is 0.3% of the total, because a full-blown simulation of a complicated process won't necessarily result in a "perfectly normal" distribution. If you wanted to specify an actual percent, you'd have to do that explicitly without invoking the concept of standard deviation.

Comment: @uhoh hm. that sounds like a wise way to do things; that doesn't sound like what I've seen personally. My recollection is something very much like "because some small number of these simulation cases will have some kind of extreme perturbation because of how we've distributed the input variables, we'll naively say that some small number of the output trajectories are going to be real bad, but only a small number of them should be.  now run 10,000." It might be worth making the Gaussian separate answer, especially if you have an example

Comment: @uhoh The problem here is that angular error as a single axis rotation is not Gaussian. Similarly, the distance error for hitting the center of the docking port is not Gaussian. Neither the angular error nor the distance error can be negative, and the probability of the error being exactly zero typically is zero (zero is a sample space of measure zero). Some people at NASA have actually read [The Handbook](https://standards.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/standards/NASA/Baseline/0/nasa-hdbk-873919-4.pdf) and have started writing more specific requirements. (continued)

Comment: These more specific requirements do a better job of specifying what is to be measured, the conditions under which they are measured (e.g., different requirements for presence or absence of faults) specific probabilities as opposed to "3σ", specific confidence levels, and whether to address issues related to a finite sample size.

Comment: @DavidHammen which is why I commented. Normal distributions are for statistics homework problems.

Comment: @DavidHammen hmm. now you've got me wondering if I've seen a total angular requirement that had a zero mean and some three-sigma-limit.  I'm absolutely sure of the RSS thing because I remember being confused about how it could possibly be close to right (the answer might've been small-angle approximation?) but all my requirements stuff was pre-COVID

Comment: @uhoh that wouldn't be the first or last thing that I saw in my engineering career that was done laughably inexpertly because it seemed good enough.  If you think my answer needs correcting, I really don't think I'm going to get the correction right, so I entreat you to either make an edit or add another answer.  Comments are supposedly temporary.

Comment: @uhoh I ran across the "3σ" requirement multiple times during my career. Such requirements typically do not assume a Gaussian distribution. They simply mean 99.73% of the test cases must pass, most likely not adjusted for a finite sample size.

Comment: @DavidHammen I've never seen that in a technical spec in the semiconductor industry - if they want a percent fail limit they specify a percent fail limit, if they want an Gaussian fit with a 3σ value they specify a Gaussian fit with a 3σ value. I've never seen one used for the other, but perhaps using one when meaning the other is "good enough for government work".